# change color of all cells under a table header when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered  ">

    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Mon </th>
        <th>Tue</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> 07:00 </td> 
        <td> </td> 
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 08:00 </td> 
        <td> </td> 
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 09:00 </td> 
        <td> </td> 
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When user click on the header, let's say, when Mon is clicked, I would like to change color of all cells under that (the whole column under the header Mon).

How can I achieve that.

Thank you!

Comment: How about at least a cide snippet which shows off your own efforts?

Comment: i think you must show us your try , you can do that with pure css or with javascript

Comment: This is a pretty simple problem. Here's a hint... a table cell has a `.cellIndex` property. But just asking how to do it is not good. If you can't even begin to solve this, then read a beginner's tutorial, or hire someone.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, next time I will ask for a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, you need to set either a class or data attributes and listen for the click. Here is a working example.

```js
$('.day').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var elem;
  var dataId;

  $this.toggleClass('active');

  dataId = $this.data('id');
  elem = $('#body-table').find('td');

  elem.each(function() {
    tdDataId = $(this).data('id');
    if (dataId == tdDataId) {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
#header-table {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#header-table .day.active {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
#body-table td.selected {
  background: #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">

  <thead id="header-table">
    <tr>
      <th data-id="sunday" class="day sunday">Sunday</th>
      <th data-id="monday" class="day monday">Monday</th>
      <th data-id="tuesday" class="day tuesday">Tuesday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="body-table">
    <tr>
      <td data-id="sunday">07:00</td>
      <td data-id="monday">07:00</td>
      <td data-id="tuesday">07:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-id="sunday">08:00</td>
      <td data-id="monday">08:00</td>
      <td data-id="tuesday">08:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-id="sunday">09:00</td>
      <td data-id="monday">09:00</td>
      <td data-id="tuesday">09:00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```